# Class DescriptorExtractor not available in opencv 4.1.0 for Android

Tags: android, opencv, contour

Im pretty new at openCV and I'm working with some documentation intended to work with openCV 3, I'm writing a filter which uses `org.opencv.features2d.DescriptorExtractor` class, however, the class is not available in openCV 4.1.0.

What I need is to use the existing classes in openCV 4.1.0 in order to achieve the same goal since I cannot use `DescriptorExtractor`.

The app recognizes certain arbitrary, rectangular images, for example, paintings, and determine their pose in a 2D projection. The app will draw an outline around a tracked image when it appears in the camera feed.

Here is the section of the code using the missing class:

```
public final class ImageDetectionFilter {

    // Not relevant section...

    // A descriptor extractor, which creates descriptors of features.
    private final DescriptorExtractor mDescriptorExtractor =
        DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.ORB);

    public ImageDetectionFilter(final Context context,
                            final int referenceImageResourceID) throws IOException {

        // Not relevant section...

        // Detect the reference features and compute their descriptors.
        mFeatureDetector.detect(referenceImageGray, mReferenceKeypoints);
        mDescriptorExtractor.compute(referenceImageGray, mReferenceKeypoints, mReferenceDescriptors);
    }

    @Override
    public void apply(final Mat src, final Mat dst) {

        // ...

        // Detect the scene features, compute their descriptors,
        // and match the scene descriptors to reference descriptors.
        mFeatureDetector.detect(mGraySrc, mSceneKeypoints);
        mDescriptorExtractor.compute(mGraySrc, mSceneKeypoints, mSceneDescriptors);
        mDescriptorMatcher.match(mSceneDescriptors, mReferenceDescriptors, mMatches);

        //...
    }
}
```

Here is the full class for your reference just in case:

```
package com.sample.opencv.filters;

import android.content.Context;

import org.opencv.android.Utils;
import org.opencv.calib3d.Calib3d;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.DMatch;
import org.opencv.core.KeyPoint;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfDMatch;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfKeyPoint;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint2f;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.features2d.DescriptorExtractor;
import org.opencv.features2d.DescriptorMatcher;
import org.opencv.features2d.ORB;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public final class ImageDetectionFilter implements Filter {

    // The reference image (this detector's target).
    private final Mat mReferenceImage;
    // Features of the reference image.
    private final MatOfKeyPoint mReferenceKeypoints =
        new MatOfKeyPoint();
    // Descriptors of the reference image's features.
    private final Mat mReferenceDescriptors = new Mat();
    // The corner coordinates of the reference image, in pixels.
    // CvType defines the color depth, number of channels, and
    // channel layout in the image. Here, each point is represented
    // by two 32-bit floats.
    private final Mat mReferenceCorners =
        new Mat(4, 1, CvType.CV_32FC2);

    // Features of the scene (the current frame).
    private final MatOfKeyPoint mSceneKeypoints =
        new MatOfKeyPoint();
    // Descriptors of the scene's features.
    private final Mat mSceneDescriptors = new Mat();
    // Tentative corner coordinates detected in the scene, in
    // pixels.
    private final Mat mCandidateSceneCorners =
        new Mat(4, 1, CvType.CV_32FC2);
    // Good corner coordinates detected in the scene, in pixels.
    private final Mat mSceneCorners = new Mat(4, 1, CvType.CV_32FC2);
    // The good detected corner coordinates, in pixels, as integers.
    private final MatOfPoint mIntSceneCorners = new MatOfPoint();

    // A grayscale version of the scene.
    private final Mat mGraySrc = new Mat();
    // Tentative matches of scene features and reference features.
    private final MatOfDMatch mMatches = new MatOfDMatch();

    // A feature detector, which finds features in images.
    private final ORB mFeatureDetector =
        ORB.create();
    // A descriptor extractor, which creates descriptors of
    // features.
    private final DescriptorExtractor mDescriptorExtractor =
        DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.ORB);
    // A descriptor matcher, which matches features based on their descriptors.
    private final DescriptorMatcher mDescriptorMatcher =
        DescriptorMatcher.create(
                DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_HAMMINGLUT);

    // The color of the outline drawn around the detected image.
    private final Scalar mLineColor = new Scalar(0, 255, 0);

    public ImageDetectionFilter(final Context context,
                            final int referenceImageResourceID) throws IOException {

        // Load the reference image from the app's resources.
        // It is loaded in BGR (blue, green, red) format.
        mReferenceImage = Utils.loadResource(context,
            referenceImageResourceID,
            Imgcodecs.IMREAD_COLOR);

        // Create grayscale and RGBA versions of the reference image.
        final Mat referenceImageGray = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mReferenceImage, referenceImageGray,
            Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mReferenceImage, mReferenceImage,
            Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGBA);

        // Store the reference image's corner coordinates, in pixels.
        mReferenceCorners.put(0, 0,
            new double[]{0.0, 0.0});
        mReferenceCorners.put(1, 0,
            new double[]{referenceImageGray.cols(), 0.0});
        mReferenceCorners.put(2, 0,
            new double[]{referenceImageGray.cols(),
                    referenceImageGray.rows()});
        mReferenceCorners.put(3, 0,
            new double[]{0.0, referenceImageGray.rows()});

        // Detect the reference features and compute their descriptors.
        mFeatureDetector.detect(referenceImageGray,
            mReferenceKeypoints);
        mDescriptorExtractor.compute(referenceImageGray,
            mReferenceKeypoints, mReferenceDescriptors);
    }

    @Override
    public void apply(final Mat src, final Mat dst) {

        // Convert the scene to grayscale.
        Imgproc.cvtColor(src, mGraySrc, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);

        // Detect the scene features, compute their descriptors,
        // and match the scene descriptors to reference descriptors.
        mFeatureDetector.detect(mGraySrc, mSceneKeypoints);
        mDescriptorExtractor.compute(mGraySrc, mSceneKeypoints,
            mSceneDescriptors);
        mDescriptorMatcher.match(mSceneDescriptors,
            mReferenceDescriptors, mMatches);

        // Attempt to find the target image's corners in the scene.
        findSceneCorners();

        // If the corners have been found, draw an outline around the
        // target image.
        // Else, draw a thumbnail of the target image.
        draw(src, dst);
    }

    private void findSceneCorners() {

        final List<DMatch> matchesList = mMatches.toList();
        if (matchesList.size() < 4) {
            // There are too few matches to find the homography.
            return;
        }

        final List<KeyPoint> referenceKeypointsList =
            mReferenceKeypoints.toList();
        final List<KeyPoint> sceneKeypointsList =
            mSceneKeypoints.toList();

        // Calculate the max and min distances between keypoints.
        double maxDist = 0.0;
        double minDist = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (final DMatch match : matchesList) {
            final double dist = match.distance;
            if (dist < minDist) {
                minDist = dist;
            }
            if (dist > maxDist) {
                maxDist = dist;
            }
        }

        // The thresholds for minDist are chosen subjectively
        // based on testing. The unit is not related to pixel
        // distances; it is related to the number of failed tests
        // for similarity between the matched descriptors.
        if (minDist > 50.0) {
            // The target is completely lost.
            // Discard any previously found corners.
            mSceneCorners.create(0, 0, mSceneCorners.type());
            return;
        } else if (minDist > 25.0) {
            // The target is lost but maybe it is still close.
            // Keep any previously found corners.
            return;
        }

        // Identify "good" keypoints based on match distance.
        final ArrayList<Point> goodReferencePointsList =
            new ArrayList<Point>();
        final ArrayList<Point> goodScenePointsList =
            new ArrayList<Point>();
        final double maxGoodMatchDist = 1.75 * minDist;
        for (final DMatch match : matchesList) {
            if (match.distance < maxGoodMatchDist) {
                goodReferencePointsList.add(
                    referenceKeypointsList.get(match.trainIdx).pt);
                goodScenePointsList.add(
                    sceneKeypointsList.get(match.queryIdx).pt);
            }
        }

        if (goodReferencePointsList.size() < 4 ||
            goodScenePointsList.size() < 4) {
            // There are too few good points to find the homography.
            return;
        }

        // There are enough good points to find the homography.
        // (Otherwise, the method would have already returned.)

        // Convert the matched points to MatOfPoint2f format, as
        // required by the Calib3d.findHomography function.
        final MatOfPoint2f goodReferencePoints = new MatOfPoint2f();
        goodReferencePoints.fromList(goodReferencePointsList);
        final MatOfPoint2f goodScenePoints = new MatOfPoint2f();
        goodScenePoints.fromList(goodScenePointsList);

        // Find the homography.
        final Mat homography = Calib3d.findHomography(
            goodReferencePoints, goodScenePoints);

        // Use the homography to project the reference corner
        // coordinates into scene coordinates.
        Core.perspectiveTransform(mReferenceCorners,
            mCandidateSceneCorners, homography);

        // Convert the scene corners to integer format, as required
        // by the Imgproc.isContourConvex function.
        mCandidateSceneCorners.convertTo(mIntSceneCorners,
            CvType.CV_32S);

        // Check whether the corners form a convex polygon. If not,
        // (that is, if the corners form a concave polygon), the
        // detection result is invalid because no real perspective can
        // make the corners of a rectangular image look like a concave
        // polygon!
        if (Imgproc.isContourConvex(mIntSceneCorners)) {
            // The corners form a convex polygon, so record them as
            // valid scene corners.
            mCandidateSceneCorners.copyTo(mSceneCorners);
        }
    }

    protected void draw(final Mat src, final Mat dst) {

        if (dst != src) {
            src.copyTo(dst);
        }

        if (mSceneCorners.height() < 4) {
            // The target has not been found.

            // Draw a thumbnail of the target in the upper-left
            // corner so that the user knows what it is.

            // Compute the thumbnail's larger dimension as half the
            // video frame's smaller dimension.
            int height = mReferenceImage.height();
            int width = mReferenceImage.width();
            final int maxDimension = Math.min(dst.width(),
                dst.height()) / 2;
            final double aspectRatio = width / (double) height;
            if (height > width) {
                height = maxDimension;
                width = (int) (height * aspectRatio);
            } else {
                width = maxDimension;
                height = (int) (width / aspectRatio);
            }

            // Select the region of interest (ROI) where the thumbnail
            // will be drawn.
            final Mat dstROI = dst.submat(0, height, 0, width);

            // Copy a resized reference image into the ROI.
            Imgproc.resize(mReferenceImage, dstROI, dstROI.size(),
                0.0, 0.0, Imgproc.INTER_AREA);

            return;
        }

        // Outline the found target in green.
        Imgproc.line(dst, new Point(mSceneCorners.get(0, 0)),
            new Point(mSceneCorners.get(1, 0)), mLineColor, 4);
        Imgproc.line(dst, new Point(mSceneCorners.get(1, 0)),
            new Point(mSceneCorners.get(2, 0)), mLineColor, 4);
        Imgproc.line(dst, new Point(mSceneCorners.get(2, 0)),
            new Point(mSceneCorners.get(3, 0)), mLineColor, 4);
        Imgproc.line(dst, new Point(mSceneCorners.get(3, 0)),
            new Point(mSceneCorners.get(0, 0)), mLineColor, 4);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrade to a lower version of opencv, 3.4.9 worked for me!